# Disable browser back action to external page using javascript / jquery in MVC application

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

I know this will be a duplicate question, but I am asking this after being frustrated for three days.

I am lending on my site's page after completing payment on external payment site. There are scenrios where user have clicked a back button and they have been charged twice or more due to it hence I want to disable back action to that page.

I have tried many answers available here on stack overflow. Below is one of the most commonly answered solution which I have tried

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        history.pushState(null, null, location.href)
        history.back();
        history.forward();
        window.onpopstate = function(){
            history.go(1);
        }
    });
</script>
```

referenced from
[Disable browser back action using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39932944/disable-browser-back-action-using-jquery)

Also,
https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/8721521?hl=en

It will be really greatfull if anybody can help guide me in right direction.

Additional Information:

- Chrome version - 100.0.4896.75
- Edge version - 100.0.1185.36

Comment: Could you elaborate more on how that didn't work for you?

Comment: This script I have placed on the lending page after completing payment on external payment site & verified script execution using an alert. when I press back button it doesn't do what it inteded to do.

Comment: That is  more or less what I use, except there is no need to wait for the document to be "ready".

Comment: @Booboo Are you lending on your page from external website?

Comment: @AkashPatel Yes, I am.

Comment: @AkashPatel And I just verified that the code no longer seems to be working correctly! However, if I start the inspector by right-mouse clicking and selecting *Inspect* in either Chrome or Edge and then hit the back button, then the code seems to be working fine. VERY STRANGE! I am now following this post since I need a resolution, too,

Comment: I have more info: It's not opening the Inspector that causes the back button to work. I find that as long as you click anywhere on the window *before* attempting to hit the back button, then everything works as expected. Otherwise, the *popstate* event is never fired. The same behavior exists for both Chrome and Edge. Also, doing a `history.back(); history.forward();` sequence in the code doesn't seem to make a bit of difference one way or another and I wouldn't expect it to be required if everything were working correctly. They do cause the `popstate` events to occur, however.

Answer (score 6):

What you are trying to achieve is called "backbutton hijacking". And it seems Chrome has added a fix to the hack you are currently using. Usually, this was used by malicious sites. You can read more here: https://www.pcmag.com/news/chrome-browser-to-stop-websites-abusing-the-back-button. In other words, if there is no user interaction the website should not stop the user from using the back button.

---

I would recommend that you discuss this problem with your payment provider. They should never make the same payment twice for the same order.

Which payment provider are you using?